# Ocave function for drawnow

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I want to make a kind of real time audio tool in octave.
In matlab there is the option to replot (drawnow) a (sub)plot and build a kind of gui around it.
Is this in octave also possible i can't find anythind about it..

thanks

Comment: Pehaps you want to have a look at LTFAT where they do a lot of realtime audio processing in octave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0S3j1PqYfQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's two questions:

1. `drawnow()` exists in Octave for a very long time
2. building a GUI in Octave will require at least version 4.0.0 (still unreleased) and qt graphics toolkit